PHP Redis is able to set key-value but unable to find keys with scan or key
I have a PHP application that is able to successfully connect to a Redis serverless endpoint on AWS using TLS. I am also able to successfully set and get cache from Redis, however, I am unable to find keys in order to invalidate the cache store.
I have successfully confirmed that the keys exist using redis-cli from the terminal.
In my PHP app I generate cache keys using the following code
private static function generateCacheKey($prefix, $identifier = null) {
    $dbName = self::$dbName;
    $appDbName = self::$useAppDB ? self::$dbNameApp : 'ks';
    $deploymentSalt = defined('KYTE_DEPLOYMENT_SALT') ? KYTE_DEPLOYMENT_SALT : 'default_kyte_salt';
    $key = "{$deploymentSalt}:{$dbName}:{$appDbName}:{$prefix}";
    if ($identifier) {
        $key .= ":{$identifier}";
    }
    return $key;
}

I am able to successfully store a value in Redis as follows:
public static function select($table, $id = null, $condition = null, $join = null) {
    $cacheKey = self::generateCacheKey("select:$table", md5("$id:$condition:" . json_encode($join)));
    $cachedResult = self::$redis ? self::$redis->get($cacheKey) : null;

    if ($cachedResult) {
        return json_decode($cachedResult, true);
    }

    /* if no cache was found, rest of the select query function */

    // after successfully retrieving data from DB, create a new cache to store
    if (self::$redis) {
        if (self::$redisTTL > 0) {
            self::$redis->set($cacheKey, json_encode($data), self::$redisTTL);
        } else {
            self::$redis->set($cacheKey, json_encode($data));
        }
    }

    return $data;
}

When there is an insert, update, or delete, I invalidate the cache by calling:
self::invalidateCache($table);

(function definition below)
The issue is that I am unable to find the patters using keys or scan even though I have confirmed they exist using redis-cli and the pattern that outputs in the error log. What could I be missing here?
Here is the code for invalidateCache
private static function invalidateCache($table) {
    if (self::$redis) {
        try {
            $pattern = self::generateCacheKey("select:$table", "*");
            error_log("Generated pattern: $pattern");

            // Fetch all matching keys using KEYS command
            $keys = self::$redis->keys($pattern);
            if (!empty($keys)) {
                error_log("Keys found for pattern {$pattern}: " . print_r($keys, true));
                foreach ($keys as $key) {
                    self::$redis->del($key);
                }
            } else {
                error_log("No keys matched the pattern {$pattern}");
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            error_log("Redis error while invalidating cache for table $table: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        error_log("Redis is not initialized.");
    }       
}

PHP redis package was installed using Pecl. I am using Redis v7.1 on AWS.

It would be better in general to have smaller keys with not that kinda fuzzy schema as a string. You can have an md5 salt of your original key stored, this will also make the memory footprint smaller and the selection not needing that much string conversion.

Thanks for your feedback! Let me implement a version that does what you suggested and see if the key size is part of the issue.
